# How to include HTML/text file without ajax call or server side language

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, include, requirejs

#### Background information :

A tool simulates IE behavior, instead of HTML for browser, it uses a special object which  contains html segment`<![CDATA[ HTML Here or JS here  ]]>`. **The tool disabled the ajax call**; however, the activeX works on that tool. In other words, HTML display in browser = special object display. No server side language (i.e. php) allowed.

#### Problem :

The object developed for that tool contains everything(html+css+js) in one single file. Then it makes developer difficult to manage changes. Currently, when I develop, I copied the HTML from `<![CDATA[ All HTML or JS here  ]]>`; after I modified it , I copied the html file back to `<![CDATA[ HTML Here or JS here  ]]>`.  I want the object is more organized, for example: in the html segment of the object, just put something like  `<![CDATA[<javascript>require a.html<javascript> ]]>` , then  the content in a.html will be automatically placed in the object. Can you suggest any solution or any library for this problem?

ps: I didn't use requirejs before, it seems requirejs uses ajax call to include text file, is it possible that requirejs uses local path to include a file?

Thank you.

---

Partial solution to my problem: I used activeX to read the entire file, and used jQuery to set the file content to some html element. so the js will look like:

`<![CDATA[
<script>var k = readfile(getAbsolutePath()+"\\a.html");
 jQuery("#display").html(k);<script> ]]>`

I think this solution is for my tool only; To make it work, some requirements:
1. can get the absolute path of the text/html file.
2. activeX works.

Comment: I'm trying to understand what you are asking here. "Change the tool you use" would be a perfectly legal answer...

Comment: I cannot change the tool which simulated IE behavior, the tool is the platform to develop. The developed product is the object which contains `<![CDATA[ HTML Here or JS here ]]>`... If the tool has all the features of modern browser, then no such problem at all lol

Comment: So, your question is "how can I improve my debugging method", but you won't tell us the "tool", or describe what you actually want to do?

Comment: it is not about debugging. the problem is how to include local files in html without php or ajax call.  js/css files is possible to be included though <link>, but how about local text files or local html files? The background information is just to explain why I couldn't use ajax call or php to solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

OK, now that I understood your problem.

Use

```
<iframe src="another_file.html">
```

That is probably the only way to load multiple html files without Ajax or PHP, as far as I know.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yep, it works in modern browser, but that tool also disabled iframe, I think it is for security reason..I am also not very sure about the working mechanism of the tool. I used activeX to read local files, and use jquery to set innerHTML to that file content. But it still does not solve the problem because the path is absolute. I used window.location.pathname, but it does not point to the correct address

Comment: Do you have physical access to the person who made the tool? I mean: if they disabled every possibility of including anything rather than your basic HTML and Javascript, they may have a reason to do so.

Comment: Yep, I just found that I could get the relative path from the tool, so I can use activeX to solve the problem :)

Comment: Great. Maybe you should post an answer on how you actually solved it, for others with similar problems.

Answer (score -2):

Per comment from prytsh, using an embed call should do the trick in HTML5:

Answer (score -3):

You can try this by using jquery

```
//use this line in jquery  
$("#id").load("trackingCode.html");
```

Comment: you can use it without AJAX.

Comment: You can use load() function or
you can use <embed src="yourfile.html">
it will work.